# What difference would it make by changing the forms of a verb?

Tags: difference

My teacher said a sentence:

> The distance between the **transmit** and the **receive** antenna is kept small.

I believe the verbs in bold have been used as adjectives here(nominalized). What difference would it make if I say the same sentence as

> The distance between the **transmitting** and the **receiving** antenna is kept small.
>
> The distance between the **transmitter** and the **receiver** antenna is kept small.

Comment: Your teacher, if this is really what he or she said, does not speak English well enough to teach it to you.

Comment: @P.E.Dant Have the verbs been nominalised and being used as adjective?

Comment: In "transmit antenna", the unmarked infinitive is nominalized and used, as if it were an adjunct noun, to modify "antenna".

Comment: You should understand that use of the nominalized unmarked infinitive as an adjunct modifier, as in these sentences, is not considered "good" writing by many who have an opinion on such matters. It might be an acceptable usage in informal writing, but it would not be appropriate in academic or other formal writing. There are grammarians who argue that it is not grammatical. It reads, to me, as stilted.

Answer (score 1):

None of the bold words are verbs.  In the first two example sentences they are [adjectives](http://www.grammar.cl/Notes/Adjectives_ED_ING.htm).  So, yes, you can use them interchangeably as you have shown.

However, I would like to correct your third example sentence.  The "er" ending makes the word a noun, not an adjective, so the words in this sentence structure are not correct.  The sentence should be:

> The distance between the antennae used by the transmitter and the receiver is small.

The "er" ending identifies a person or thing that does what the noun describes.  A "transmitter" is something (like a radio) or someone (like a sick person) that transmits (a signal or a disease).

Note also the plural form of the word "antenna" is "antennae."

Comment: Some dictionaries argue that antennae should be reserved for an insect's feelers while metal rods for receiving-transmitting should be named antennas. Some permit both.

Comment: The English language has always had a love-hate relationship with plurals not ending with an "s."  But, that's what makes it fun, isn't it?

Comment: @JBH As you said, "None of the bold words are verbs." I know they are acting as adjectives already but the form in which they are written is mostly used as a verb only.

Comment: @AnubhavSingh, did I fail to understand your question?  Have I not provided an appropriate answer?

Comment: Well. Your answer seems good but if you could also point out about the alternatives suggested by me. The alternative with gerund adjective seems fine to me.

Comment: @AnubhavSingh, it is fine.  As I said in my first paragraph,  "In the first two example sentences they are adjectives. So, yes, you can use them interchangeably as you have shown."

Comment: @JBH Just a last question: Using transmit and receive antennae is fine in the first sentence? Why?

Comment: "Antennae" is the plural of "antenna," so it is the preferred noun.  It is common in technical terms to use the nomnative form of a predicate adjective.  They become "labels."  Grammatically, the second example sentence is the most correct, but I doubt an English teacher with technical terms would be upset by the use of the first example sentence.

Comment: I believe the same concept holds true for the "transmit gain" and the "write mode of channel".